# ItemTemplate with image

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

Hello I am currently working on a project and are using Listbox.ItemTemplate.
I am trying to make the template look like this:

```
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="10" Width="100" Height="100" >
                //Image here//
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

The thing is that I add the items manually with the help of a c# method.
Does anyone know how I add a temple to a item as shown above?

Answer (score 0):

If you add the template to the `ListBox` (as you've done above) then any items added to the listbox will have that template applied to them. The template applies to *all* items in the listbox.